# virtio-kmod in /usr/ports is not compatible; what can I do?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports, virtio

I tried to install virtio-kmod in a FreeBSD guest.

`make` in `/usr/ports/emulators/virtio-kmod` gives `virtio-kmod--0.250249 not supported ${OSREL} (10.1)`.

The ports-tree is up to date.

Is that a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `virtio` drivers are included in FreeBSD 10.1, so there's no need to install the port, hence the error message. (Perhaps it could be made clearer). So all you need to do is `kldload virtio` or `kldload virtio_blk`. Though in many situations where you need these, they're going to be already loaded for you at boot.